# Windows 7/Ubuntu dual boot help?

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I installed ubuntu and was running it for a month before I wanted windows back to run some programs that I couldn't run on ubuntu. I had accidentally deleted my recovery partition and overwrote windows when I installed ubuntu. I eventually got windows 7 back on my computer but now I don't know how to boot up ubuntu again. I still have ubuntu on a bootable partition and windows is on it's on bootable partition. Can anyone tell me how I can boot up ubuntu again? thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can install boot-repair and repair grub. so that you can dual boot. Create a ubuntu live usb/cd, boot from that and install boot-repair. Here is how to repair grub http://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/

Answer (score 1):

Try using [EasyBCD](https://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) to add Ubuntu to your windows bootloader.

After you install it, run the program and click `Add new entry`, then click the `Linux/BSD` tab, then choose `GRUB2` on the type and type `Ubuntu` in the name box. For the drive box, either leave it on `Automatically locate and load` or select the partition/drive Ubuntu is on. Now click `Add Entry`. After you have done this, click `BCD Deployment` at the left side, and press `Write MBR`.

This should take you to either Ubuntu, or the GRUB2 boot menu, where you can continue on to Ubuntu, depending on your settings.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what happened.

Windows is dumb.  It thinks that it's bootloader is the best, thus when installing windows 7, it will install itself over grub.  No since windows is dumb, it can't see the ext file systems, so it can't tell that grub is there.  You see two answeres above.  The first one suggests neosmart easybcd.  That is a fine option, probably the easiest, but there is another.  The boot repair disk.

Why the choices?

With easy bcd, the program adds Ubuntu into the windows boot loader.  With boot repair disk, it reinstalls grub2.

So it's your choice.  Do you like the (ugly) windows boot menu, or the very customizable (and awesome) grub2 boot loader.

Most people would rather go with grub.

I would install grub, and then burg.  Google burg.

This isn't so much a Ubuntu related question.  Of course, boot repair disk is based off of Ubuntu core files, though.

Every time you install a new version of windows, you will need to boot into the boot repair disk, and reinstall grub to the MBR.

You'd think windows would just give you the option to write wbm to the MBR :)

Answer (score 0):

- Start live boot with ubuntu (select Try ubuntu option)
- Open terminal command using
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- Type follow command and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

  `sudo apt-get install grub2 grub-pc`

  then run:

  `sudo update-grub`
- Reboot your computer and remove Ubuntu live boot device (ex: DVD or
  USB drive).

Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

You need to recover your GRUB:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows