# Recover Windows 7 Boot Loader

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 14.04, windows-7, bootloader

I have mistakenly removed Windows 7 boot loader from my primary drive, when I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

I would like to have both OSs on my machine. At this moment, Windows 7 is on SDA2, Ubuntu is on SDA1.

How can I recover the previous loader for Windows 7 and options with dual boot?

Comment: See my answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/483469/windows-7-ubuntu-dual-boot-help/483951#483951)

Comment: If the Windows boot loader has been removed or overwritten, then you won't be able to boot Windows, and you must fix the problem with Windows tools. You might then need to restore or re-install GRUB, depending on how it was installed to begin with and how Windows restored its boot loader.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know what your "previous loader" was?

You may want to install GRUB: https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/Installing-GRUB-using-grub_002dinstall.html

which can load a menu on boot displaying each operating system available

You also may just need to run boot-repair: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

this utility can repair grub configurations, and should provide you with the means to access both Ubuntu and Windows.